# Is itoa() available in stdlib.h in Gcc >=4.1?

Tags: 10.10, programming, gcc

that's my question. I've Gcc 4.4.1 and that function isn’t present, i had installed the 4.3 and 4.5 versions with the same result :-/

I know that this function is not the C-ANSI standard, but I didn't write the code and I need compile it in my distro. A friend of mine had the same version of the compiler in Fedora, and Gcc compiles with no problem (using stdio.h and stdlib.h).

So if someone can tell me if the function is/isn't available in my compiler.. I'd be thankful.

Greetings.

btw: this my gcc version:

```
:~$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear to be defined in 4.4.4, but if you don't care about radixes other than 10

```
char *itoa(long i, char* s, int dummy_radix) {
    sprintf(s, "%ld", i);
    return s;
}
```

Is a quick and dirty (and tested) replacement.

Comment: Sounds like they want to compile a software package that uses the function

Comment: And their suite lacks the function which one would need to compile it. So there is the function ready for linking. Am i missing some subtle point you are trying to make?

Comment: thank for the hand stefano, i had used another function similar to yours. Greetings.

Comment: Give us a usage example.

Answer (score 1):

```
 void itoa(int n, char s[])
 {
 int i, sign;

 if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* записываем знак */
     n = -n;          /* делаем n положительным числом */
 i = 0;
 do {       /* генерируем цифры в обратном порядке */
     s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* берем следующую цифру */
 } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* удаляем */
 if (sign < 0)
     s[i++] = '-';
 s[i] = '\0';
 reverse(s);
 }
```

And if you need the reverse function:

```
#include <string.h>

/* reverse:  переворачиваем строку s на месте */
void reverse(char s[])
{
 int i, j;
 char c;

 for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
     c = s[i];
     s[i] = s[j];
     s[j] = c;
 }
}
```

I have got this implementation from the Russian Wikipaedia.